# how to invert matplotlib pyplot pcolor cmap

Tags: python, matplotlib

To illustrate my question, I will generate a simple heatmap.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

heatmap = np.asarray([[20, 0, 40],
                      [0, 40, 40],
                      [20, 40, 50]])

heatmap_plot = plt.pcolor(heatmap, cmap='RdBu', vmin=0, vmax=100)
plt.show()
```

This produces the following image;

[image]

Here, one can see that the lower values appear as darker red, and the larger values approach white. How do i reverse this setting? I other words, how do I make lower values lighter shades (0 = white). and larger values represent darker colors, in this case, red.

I couldn't seem to find any such parameter looking at the [pcolor documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor).

Comment: Is it an option to simply plot the negative of your data?:) I.e. plotting `-heatmap` with `-vmin`, `-vmax`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add _r to your cmap. Your new cmap is RdBu_r.